# Javascript and HTML getElementById mysterious disfunctionality

Tags: javascript, html

so here is my code.

here is the HTML

```
    <html>

    <head>

        <script src  = "Thing.js" type = "text/javascript">
    </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <h2 id = "warning"> You are going down mate</h2>

    <input type = "button" value = "Raid" onclick = "sayHi()" />
    </body>


</html>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
function sayHi(){
    var warner = getElementById("warning");
    alert(warner);
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, it doesn't work. also I am using sublime-text and I am on google chrome if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: you're missing `document`, so it is`document.getElementById("warning");`

Comment: Further to what others have said - I imagine you'd like to show the msg `" You are going down mate"`. If so, use this: `alert( document.getElementById('warning').innerText );`

Comment: @enhzflep **Never** use `.innerText`. It's not standard and doesn't exist in Firefox. Use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`.

Comment: *"The problem is that when I run it, it doesn't work."* You should be more specific. What exactly doesn't work? Which errors do you get? We expect that you do some debugging on your own. If you don't know how to debug JavaScript, make yourself familiar with your browser's developer tools before you do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the alarm to say the text. If so use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), <del>[`innerText`]</del>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). As itsgoingdown and guest271314 have already stated, use `document` as in `document.getElementById()`.

**Edit**

Barmar advises:

> **Never** use `.innerText`. It's not standard and doesn't exist in Firefox. Use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`

```js
function sayHi() {
  var warner = document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML;
  alert(warner);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="Thing.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="warning"> You are going down mate</h2>

  <input type="button" value="Raid" onclick="sayHi()" />
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is not a method of global `window` : `this` within `sayHi` function. Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: Can you please re-write my code? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @Syndromez At `javascript` at Question only `getElementById()` is used. `getElementById()` is a method of `document`. If expected result is to alert the text content of `#warning` element, you can adjust existing `javascript` to include `document` before `.getElementById()`, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) chained to `document.getElementById("warning")` to `alert` text instead of `DOM` element `#warning`; for example `function sayHi(){
    var warner = document.getElementById("warning").textContent;
    alert(warner);
}`